# Usage of Inline for constructors and Destructors in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, inline, destructor

I am new to C++.I was told not to use Inline with Constructors(containing user defined datatypes as arguments) and destructors.

Is there any such thing in C++?

I think it is fine to use Inline for constructors and destructors as long as they are short and simple(not complicated).

Can someone help me out.An example would help.Thanks.

Comment: You were told nonsense. It's perfectly fine to use `inline` with constructors and destructors. Note though that using `inline` for optimisation is pretty worthless. The only real use is to allow you to place code in headers.

Comment: @Simple What are the uses of having the code in the headers?

Comment: @starkk92 It can allow the compiler to perform more aggressive optimizations, at the cost of the client code being coupled to your implementation, and code which you might need there but might not form part of a class definition.

Answer (score 3):

There is no rules like that. inline is nothing more than a hint to the compiler and it can do whatever it wants on it.

Note that methods define in the class declaration are implicitly inline, and modern compiler support link time optimisation to allow inlining cross multiple compilation unit…

So give the hint on what you think is right like short functions or constructors and trust your compiler to do what is best, it will be right at 99.9%